# How to convert a normal application icon into a downloading icon on iPhone's SpringBoard?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, springboard

I'm writing a jailbroken app in iPhone, I'd like to add a updating mechanism for this app and it works like the updating via App Store.

I know that every icon on SpringBoard is a SBApplicationIcon object, while the icon with a progress bar for updating is SBDownloadingIcon object. My problem is that I can not find any method to convert.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to update apps like it does when via App Store with the Progress Bar on it.

Try using the itms-services ([Wireless ad-hoc distribution](http://idevblog.info/wireless-ad-hoc-app-distribution/)). For that you need to create a simple plist file and the ipa and upload it to a server. It'll help you download the app in the same way App Store does.

Comment: No, I said I am developing a jailbroken app which is not available on the App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I understand since it's for jailbroken filesystem, it's not on the App Store. That's why I'm saying, upload the two files (IPA and PLIST file) to a free web server space, you can get easily.

If you can build an ipa for the app, then follow the link I mentioned above.
If it's a .deb package, then it can't be done that way, AFAIK.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You mention a link but there is no link in your answer?

Comment: @Kunal, please don't add more than one answer, just to clarify your first one.  Use the **edit** link to add more, or post a comment under your first answer, in response to the poster's comment.  Also, please don't create multiple Stack Overflow accounts.  You have two accounts, used to post two different answers here.

Comment: @Beno, I think the link is the link in the *other* answer here.  Kunal posted two answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you have to use a itms-services url. Since your code can't make itself writable, you will not be able to change the object from a SBApplicationIcon to a SBDownloadingIcon object (and back again to a SBApplicationIcon so that users can use the app).